# Custom Permalinks for Custom post Type Archives?

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, archives

I know that WP 3.1 has added support for archives for custom post types but is there any way to customize the permalinks for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an example custom post type called `movie` the code below will create custom permalinks `awesomemovies/` regardless of the one created by using the has_archive and rewrite options of register_post_type.

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'custom_permalink_for_my_cpt' );
function custom_permalink_for_my_cpt( $rules ) {
    $custom_rules = array();
    // for archive urls
    $custom_rules['awesomemovies/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=movie';

    // for individual post urls e.g: http://blog.com/awesomemovies/post-name/
    $custom_rules['awesomemovies/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=movie&pagename=$matches[1]';
    return $custom_rules + $rules;
}
```

For more information see [WP_Rewrite](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite)

Comment: That takes care of the rewrite but doesn't handle the actual creation of permalinks.

Answer (score 4):

to customize the permalink of the CPT archive? Check this out
http://mark.mcwilliams.me/2010/10/wordpress-3-1-introduces-custom-post-type-archives/

Basically just use the has_archive feature to change the permalink

```
add_action( 'init', 'mcw_projects_post_type' );

function mcw_projects_post_type() {

    register_post_type( 'projects', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Projects'),
            'singular_name' => __('Project')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'show_ui' => true,
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'project',
            'with_front' => false
            ),
        'has_archive' => true
    ) );

}
```

Is a way to register a CPT. The has_archive turns on the archive support.  Swap that out like:

```
'has_archive' => 'projects'
```

Or what have you to adjust the permalink for the CPT archive.

Or are you looking for ways to alter the permalinks with teh CPTs in general? Which is done with the rewrite parameter 
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments

Not sure which part you are trying to do

Comment: I want to create a more complex permalink for an archive, similar to how this article creates custom permalinks to single pages for post type: http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/custom-post-type-permalinks-part-2

Comment: show the right start and you can use similar code to adjust the cpt-permalink to what you want. For example, if you wish the permalink to read .../cool-project/... then you need to change the has_archive line to 'has_archive' => 'cool-project' same source: http://mark.mcwilliams.me/2010/10/wordpress-3-1-introduces-custom-post-type-archives/

Comment: Right, that's what I say under the block of code above, isn't it?