# Help with a TV series Rewrite structure

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, permalinks, rewrite-rules

Not sure if this is possible, but bear with me.  I think I am halfway there.

First a little background:  I'm using the build in hierarchy in WordPress to form relationships between post types.  I have a post type called series that holds info on a TV series.  I have another post type called content that has info on specific episodes and I use the built in post_parent field on the posts data table to point to a series.

So basically, I'm trying to do a rewrite/permalink structure similar to this for content:

http://website.com/%series-name%/%content-type%/%postname%

content-type is a taxonomy attached to content that has a few terms; episode, movie and special.

My idea to prevent rewrite collisions was to use this code, inspired by a previous question I had asked [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/19717/custom-permalinks-for-custom-post-type-archives/19720#19720)

```
add_filter( 'rewrite_rules_array', 'content_rewrite_rules',10,1);
function content_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
        $custom_rules = array();
        $type_terms = get_terms('veda_content_type', array('hide_empty'=>false));
        if(!is_wp_error($type_terms) && sizeof($type_terms) > 0) {
            foreach ($type_terms as $term) {
                $custom_rules['([^/]+)/'.$term->slug. '/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?post_type=veda_content&series_name=$matches[1]&pagename=$matches[2]';
            }
        }

        return array_merge($custom_rules , $rules);
    }
```

Using the rewrite analyzer, it seems that it sorta works, except it shows that the series_name query_var is crossed out in red and I'm not sure what that means.
[image: Rewrite 1]
My question is: is there another, more efficient way to create the permalink that I want?  Also, what the cross out mean?

EDIT:  I'm trying to see if the rewrite works and my server is giving me bad request errors

Comment: Also check out: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14513

Comment: @edelwater  I already have a good setup for doing the relationships between the post types, I just need help optimizing my rewrites.

Comment: You should go to the WPSE Plugin repository and just comment on the plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find some solutions to the problems I had above:

Red strike through in the Rewrite Analyzer plug in means that the query_var wasn't defined before hand, so WP automagically deletes them.  The other problem I had was solved here: [Using %postname% tag with a Custom Permastruct creates 400 Bad Request Errors from the server](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20913/using-postname-tag-with-a-custom-permastruct-creates-400-bad-request-errors-fro)