# Using %postname% tag with a Custom Permastruct creates 400 Bad Request Errors from the server

Tags: custom-post-types, permalinks, rewrite-rules

This is related to another question that I had asked earlier.  I'm doing some rewrite code to create some custom permalinks for a custom post type.  I think I'm getting it mostly working except I'm getting the following error:

[image: 400 Bad Request]
I noticed a few things:

1. Whatever I have as the postname gets replaced in the url field as %postname%
2. If I omit the post name, it loads up in WordPress no problem

Here is the code to setup the rewrite:

```
add_action('init', 'setup_rewrites');
function setup_rewrites() {
        global $wp_rewrite;
        //Content
        add_rewrite_tag('%seriesname%','([^/]+)');
        add_rewrite_tag('%contenttype%','([^/]+)');
        $content_struct = '/content/%seriesname%/%contenttype%/%postname%';
        add_permastruct('veda_content', $content_struct, false);

    }
```

an example url that doesn't work but should:
http://watchonepiecelegally.com/content/one-piece/episode/test-1

A URL that does work:
http://watchonepiecelegally.com/content/one-piece/episode/

What I get via Jan Fabry's Rewrite Analyzer plugin:
[image]

This should work but I'm missing something.  Can anyone give me a hand?

EDIT: As requested, here are the rewrite rules Wordpress is generating.  Hopefully this helps:

```
Array
(
    [category/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [category/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [category/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [category/(.+?)/?$] => index.php?category_name=$matches[1]
    [tag/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [tag/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [tag/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [tag/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?tag=$matches[1]
    [type/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [type/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [type/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [type/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?post_format=$matches[1]
    [anime-series/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime-series/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-series/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-series/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-series/.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime-series/(.+?)/trackback/?$] => index.php?veda_series=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-series/(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_series=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-series/(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_series=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-series/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_series=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [anime-series/(.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_series=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime-series/(.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?veda_series=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-release/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?veda_release=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-release/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_release=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_release=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_release=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_release=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?veda_release=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-release/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-release/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime_video/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?veda_video=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime_video/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_video=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_video=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_video=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_video=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?veda_video=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime_video/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_video/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?veda_purchase=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime_purchase/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_purchase=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_purchase=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_purchase=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_purchase=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?veda_purchase=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime_purchase/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-review/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?veda_review=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-review/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_review=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_review=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_review=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_review=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?veda_review=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [anime-review/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [anime-review/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [subtitle_language/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_subtitle_language=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [subtitle_language/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_subtitle_language=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [subtitle_language/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_subtitle_language=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [subtitle_language/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_subtitle_language=$matches[1]
    [audio_language/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_audio_language=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [audio_language/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_audio_language=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [audio_language/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_audio_language=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [audio_language/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_audio_language=$matches[1]
    [genre/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_genre=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [genre/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_genre=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [genre/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_genre=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [genre/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_genre=$matches[1]
    [studio/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_studio=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [studio/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_studio=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [studio/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_studio=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [studio/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_studio=$matches[1]
    [content_type/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_content_type=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content_type/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_content_type=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content_type/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_content_type=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [content_type/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_content_type=$matches[1]
    [publisher/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_publisher=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [publisher/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_publisher=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [publisher/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_publisher=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [publisher/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_publisher=$matches[1]
    [release_type/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_release_type=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [release_type/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_release_type=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [release_type/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_release_type=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [release_type/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_release_type=$matches[1]
    [release_rating/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_rating=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [release_rating/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_rating=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [release_rating/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_rating=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [release_rating/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_rating=$matches[1]
    [video_source/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_video_source=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [video_source/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_video_source=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [video_source/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_video_source=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [video_source/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_video_source=$matches[1]
    [retailer/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_retailer=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [retailer/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?veda_retailer=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [retailer/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?veda_retailer=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [retailer/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?veda_retailer=$matches[1]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&tb=1
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]&page=$matches[4]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]
    [content/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&contenttype=$matches[2]
    [content/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [content/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [content/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?seriesname=$matches[1]
    [robots\.txt$] => index.php?robots=1
    [.*wp-atom.php$] => index.php?feed=atom
    [.*wp-rdf.php$] => index.php?feed=rdf
    [.*wp-rss.php$] => index.php?feed=rss
    [.*wp-rss2.php$] => index.php?feed=rss2
    [.*wp-feed.php$] => index.php?feed=feed
    [.*wp-commentsrss2.php$] => index.php?feed=rss2&withcomments=1
    [feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
    [(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]
    [page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?&paged=$matches[1]
    [comments/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]&withcomments=1
    [comments/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?&feed=$matches[1]&withcomments=1
    [comments/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?&paged=$matches[1]
    [search/(.+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [search/(.+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [search/(.+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [search/(.+)/?$] => index.php?s=$matches[1]
    [author/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [author/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [author/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [author/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?author_name=$matches[1]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&feed=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&paged=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&feed=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&paged=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]&tb=1
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]&feed=$matches[5]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]&feed=$matches[5]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]&paged=$matches[5]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]&cpage=$matches[5]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/([^/]+)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&name=$matches[4]&page=$matches[5]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{1,2}/[0-9]{1,2}/[^/]+/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/([0-9]{1,2})/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&day=$matches[3]&cpage=$matches[4]
    [([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{1,2})/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&cpage=$matches[3]
    [([0-9]{4})/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?year=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]
    [.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/trackback/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [.+?/attachment/([^/]+)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?attachment=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [(.+?)/trackback/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&tb=1
    [(.+?)/feed/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [(.+?)/(feed|rdf|rss|rss2|atom)/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&feed=$matches[2]
    [(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]
    [(.+?)/comment-page-([0-9]{1,})/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&cpage=$matches[2]
    [(.+?)(/[0-9]+)?/?$] => index.php?pagename=$matches[1]&page=$matches[2]
)
```

%seriesname% is a slug that coincides with the parent of the post.  %contenttype% coincides with a custom taxonomy.  The idea was that if the %postname% tag was omitted, those two other tags could be used to create an archive page.

EDIT:  Making progress.  As noted in the discussion in the comments, using the builtin %postname% tag with a custom permastruct seems to be the cause of my 400 Bad Request Errors.  Hopefully this should narrow down what the problem seems to be.

Comment: What are doing with the query vars `seriesname` and `contenttype`? Post a screenshot of your [*actual* rewrite rules](http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/wordpress-internal-rewrite-viewer-plugin/).

Comment: @TheDeadMedic.  I posted the info you wanted.  Hopefully that helps.  I'm still pretty new with rewrite rules and how WordPress handles them.  For some reason, I think the problem is with the %postname% tag because for whatever reason, whatever link I give, the server redirects to a URL with '%postname%' at the end of it.  That's a big tip off for me but I don't know what it means.

Comment: Woah, that's a lotta rules ;)  `redirect_canonical()` is probably the troublemaker, but at what point (and why) I can't say. The only thing that's gonna make it easier is go back to basics; strip out all the other custom post types and taxes, go back to a simple permastruct, then add to/flush/re-test each time.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I did some rejiggering and as I suspected, for some reason the problem was using the built in %postname% tag.  I removed it and created my own custom tag to take its place and low and behold the 400 errors went away.  I have no clue why using %postname% made things go wonky, though.  Maybe mixing my custom tags with %postname% is conflicting somewhere, I don't know.

Comment: Do you have reset the rewrite rules after insert your custom post type?

Comment: @bueltge Yeah.  Using any of my own custom tags works no problem.  Using %postname% at the end with a single word works but any other slug gives me the error illustrated above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I feel stupid.

I needed to translate %postname%.  I thought it did so automatically since the admin page looked like it had but apparently if you do use custom permastructs, you have to translate even the default tags.

My solution: add this to my post_type_link filter:

```
$post = get_post($post_id);
$permalink =  str_replace('%postname%', $post->post_name, $permalink);
```

Problem solved.

Comment: This isn't working for me, despite having %postname% specified, I'm still seeing 404 errors when trying to view the single post. Can you post your full post_type_link function?